# Spark Repartition Issue

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, etl

Good day everyone,
I'm working with a project where I'm running an ETL process over millions of data records with the aid of Spark (2.4.4) and `PySpark`.

We're fetching from an S3 bucket in AWS huge compressed CSV files, converting them into Spark `Dataframes`, using the `repartition()` method and converting each piece into a `parquet` data to lighten and speed up the process:

```
        for file in files:
        if not self.__exists_parquet_in_s3(self.config['aws.output.folder'] + '/' + file, '.parquet'):
            # Run the parquet converter
            print('**** Processing %s ****' % file)
            # TODO: number of repartition variable
            df = SparkUtils.get_df_from_s3(self.spark_session, file, self.config['aws.bucket']).repartition(94)
            s3folderpath = 's3a://' + self.config['aws.bucket'] + \
                           '/' + self.config['aws.output.folder'] + \
                           '/%s' % file + '/'
            print('Writing down process')
            df.write.format('parquet').mode('append').save(
                '%s' % s3folderpath)
            print('**** Saving %s completed ****' % file)
            df.unpersist()
        else:
            print('Parquet files already exist!')
```

So as a first step this piece of code is searching inside the s3 bucket if these parquet file exists, if not it will enter the for cycle and run all the transformations.

Now, let's get to the point. I have this pipeline which is working fine with every csv file, except for one which is identical to the others except for bein much heavier also after the repartition and conversion in parquet (29 MB x 94 parts vs 900 kB x 32 parts).

This is causing a bottleneck after some time during the process (which is divided into identical cycles, where the number of cycles is equal to the number of repartitions made) raising a **java heap memory space** issue after several Warnings:

`WARN TaskSetManager: Stage X contains a task of very large size (x KB). The maximum recommended size is 100 KB`. (Also see pics below)

Part 1]:

[image: Part 1]

Part 2

[image: Part 2]

The most logical solution would be that of further increasing the repartition parameter to lower the weight of each parquet file BUT it does not allow me to create more than 94 partitions, after some time during the for cycle (above mentioned) it raises this error:

```
ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job 8fc9c89f-dccd-400c-af6f-dfb312df0c72.
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: HGC6JTRN5VT5ERRR, AWS Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch, AWS Error Message: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method., S3 Extended Request ID: 7VBu4mUEmiAWkjLoRPruTiCY3IhpK40t+lg77HDNC0lTtc8h2Zi1K1XGSnJhjwnbLagN/kS+TpQ=
```

Or also:

Second issue type, notice the warning

[image: Second issue type, notice the warning]

What I noticed is that I can under partition the files related to the original value: I can use a 16 as parameter instead of the 94 and it will run fine, but if i increase it over 94, the original value, it won't work.

Remember this pipeline is perfectly working **until the end** with other (lighter) CSV files, the only variable here seems to be the input file (size in particular) which seems to make it stop after some time. If you need any other detail please let me know, I'll be extremely glad if you help me with this. Thank you everyone in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's your logic in your `SparkUtils`, based on the code and log you provided, it looks like it doesn't relate to your resource or partitioning, it may cause by the connection between your spark application and S3:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 403
```

403: your login don't have access to the bucket/file you are trying to read/write. Although it's from the Hadoop documents about the authentication, you can see several case will cause this error: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html#Authentication_Failure. As you mentioned that you see this error during the loop but not at the beginning of your job, please check your running time of your spark job, also the IAM and session authentication as it maybe cause by session expiration (default 1 hour, based on how your DevOps team set), details your can check: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/howtosessionduration.html.